# Shopify API Configuration

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

When we created a API, I figured that I need to configure a new Shopify like this

```
const Shopify = require('shopify-api-node');

const shopify = new Shopify({
  shopName: 'your-shop-name',
  apiKey: 'your-api-key',
});
```

Is there any way to get the Shopify "your-shop-name" programmatically? So If I installed the app on another one it won't need to change. Or is there any other way to configure the API on Shopify?

I primarily need to update the product description using Admin REST API.

Answer (score 0):

In your store, where you want to change descriptions using API calls, use the Admin App section to issue yourself an API key pair. You can give that key pair permission to edit products. And you're done! You have the store name obviously, and you have your access token. Nothing to it!